# Java Script code not working

Tags: javascript

I wrote a code that tell us what is the day when the date is given, I get the inputs but I am not able to get the output and also I am able to process it.
Please Help me I had written this programm in C++ and in it, it works well but I am trying to open it in browser that the viewrs able are to reach my code without download any thing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="date_day()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function date_day()
{
 var odd1=0,odd2=0,odd3=0,odd=0;
 document.write("EXAMPLE"+"<br>"+"************************************"+"<br>");
 document.write("Enter Year:2014"+"<br>"+"Enter Month:8"+"<br>"+"Enter date:20"+"        <br>"+"Wednesday"+"<br>"+"************************************"+"<br>");
 var date = prompt("Please enter Date (DD)","1");
 var month = prompt("Please enter Month (MM)","6");
  var year = prompt("Please enter Year (YYYY)","2014");
 /*odd_1_2()*/
 var cen,yr,i;
--year;
cen=(year/100)*100;
if((cen%400)==0)
    odd1=0;
else
{
    for(i=1;i<4;i++)
    {
        cen =cen-100;
        if(cen%400==0)
            break;

    } 
    switch(i*100)
{
    case 100: odd1 +=5;break;
    case 200: odd1 +=3;break;
    case 300: odd1 +=1;break;
}
}
yr=year%100;
odd2=(((yr/4)*2)+(yr-(yr/4)))%7;
/* oddthree*/
var nd=0,mon=1;
if(mon<month&&mon==1)
{
    nd +=31;
    mon++;
}
if(mon<month&&mon==2)
{
    if(year%4==0)
    {
        nd +=29;
        mon++;
    }
    else 
    {
        nd +=28;
        mon++;
    }

}
if(mon<month&&mon==3)
{
    nd +=31;
    mon++;
}
if(mon<month&&mon==4)
{
    nd +=30;
    mon++;
}
if(mon<month&&mon==5)
{
    nd +=31;
    mon++;
}
if(mon<month&&mon==6)
{
    nd +=30;
    mon++;
}
    if(mon<month&&mon==7)
    {
    nd +=31;
    mon++;
    }
    if(mon<month&&mon==8)
    {
    nd +=31;
    mon++;
    }
    if(mon<month&&mon==9)
    {
    nd +=30;
        mon++;
    }
    if(mon<month&&mon==10)
    {
        nd +=31;
        mon++;
    }
    if(mon<month&&mon==11)
    {
    nd +=30;
    mon++;
    }
    if(mon<month&&mon==12)
    {
        nd +=31;
        mon++;
    }
    nd +=dt;
    odd3=(nd%7);
    odd=(odd3)%7;
    switch(odd)
    {
        case 0:  document.write("TheDay at "+date+"/"+month+"/"+year+"/"+" is "+"Sunday");break;
        case 1:  document.write("TheDay at "+date+"/"+month+"/"+year+"/"+" is "+"Monday");break;
        case 2:  document.write("TheDay at "+date+"/"+month+"/"+year+"/"+" is "+"Tuesday");break;
        case 3:  document.write("TheDay at "+date+"/"+month+"/"+year+"/"+" is "+"Wednesday");break;
        case 4:  document.write("TheDay at "+date+"/"+month+"/"+year+"/"+" is "+"Thrusday");break;
        case 5:  document.write("TheDay at "+date+"/"+month+"/"+year+"/"+" is "+"Friday");break;
        case 6:  document.write("TheDay at "+date+"/"+month+"/"+year+"/"+" is             "+"Saturday");break;
    }
        }


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: Don't just dump all of your code here and ask us to debug it for you.  What information do you have about the error in the code?  Is there an error message in the JavaScript console?  Unexpected output?  What indication do you have that this doesn't work as intended?  When you step through this in a debugger, where does it fail?

Comment: Your code is really dirty. Use `switch` instead of multiple `if` and do not write `mon++` everywhere, you can easily factorize it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can really simplify this by using built in function of Date object called .getDay();

check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `document.write`, this will rewrite all the html of the page.
You can use `element.innerHTML` if you want to add content to the page using javascript.

So assuming you have a `<div id="myDiv"></div>`, do the coding `document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML += data`  instead of `document.write`

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript's built-in Date object

```
var inp = prompt("Enter date");
var d = new Date(inp);
var dow = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'][d.getUTCDay()];
alert("That falls on a " + dow);
```